# Accurately measuring capacitor charge using a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, datasheet

I am working on a circuit that involves charging a capacitor and measuring the accumulated charge with a microcontroller.

From my initial tests, I have run across these challenges:

1. The capacitor once charged, slowly loses its charge by itself.
2. The simple act of measuring the voltage via microcontroller ADC, causes the capacitor to lose some charge.

My question is, where in the datasheets for the respective capacitors and microcontroller, can I find out the rates for #1 and #2 above?  Is there a name for these rates?

Comment: The rate of (1) depends heavily on the PCB design. There are techniques for minimizing it; look up guard rings. You'll need a very low input bias op amp. The rate of (2) is related to the sample-and-hold capacitance of the ADC, which may or may not be specified in the datasheet.

Comment: 1) Depends on the capacitor. Unless it is a special capacitor, self-discharge current is rarely specified, and if it specified, there likely just is a maximum which happens under some specific conditions. It might be called leakage current and it is highly unpredictable. For the current taken or given by ADC measurement, there may be no special name for it. It could also charge the capacitor, not just discharge it.